# xcodebuild [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I can able to run the code local machine. But running on Jenkins slave is failing with following error:

xcodebuild[3082:4342631] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: Could not launch simulator: -600
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace Myproject with scheme Myproject.

> Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -600.) 
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure.

-----------------script-------------------

xcodebuild \ 
-workspace Myproject.xcworkspace \ 
-scheme Myproject \ 
-sdk iphonesimulator \ 
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air 2,OS=9.2' \
 test

Comment: I can able to run the code local machine.But running on Jenkins failing.

Comment: Please include all the information in the question, instead of the comments.

Comment: Can you provide more insight about this error message?

Comment: I personally have no clue about any of this (I have no experience with xcode or Jenkins). The only thing that I can recommend that you do is see if you can make a small version of the code that also causes this error and include that in the question.

Comment: sure,thanks@Laurel :)

Comment: Have you solved it by any chance @Happy ? I am facing the same problem now.

Comment: I fixed it by restarting my mac-mini slave.

Answer (score 2):

I am resolved it bu using "Force Quit" for simulator and building project again.